# Equation in Current vector in a Klein Gordon Equation

Tags: conservation-laws, metric-tensor, klein-gordon-equation

I'm trying to get the current vector $J^\mu$ of a Klein-Gordon equation:

$$\Psi^* \Box \Psi =\Psi^* \partial^{\mu} \partial_\mu  \Psi= \partial^{\mu}(\Psi^*\partial_\mu \Psi)-\partial^\mu \Psi^*\partial_\mu \Psi  $$

$$\Psi \Box \Psi^*  =\Psi\partial^{\mu} \partial_\mu  \Psi^*= \partial^{\mu}(\Psi\partial_\mu \Psi^*)-\partial^\mu \Psi\partial_\mu \Psi^*. $$

Now I have to substract (1)-(2) so the term in the right is the same and it dissapears. My question is why are theose terms the same, I cant' see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume, for simplicity, that your fields are defined in a Euclidean or Minkowski space, with metric $\eta_{\mu \nu}$.

Then, remember that $\partial^{\mu} = \eta^{\mu \nu} \partial_{\nu}$. Thus, both terms in of the RHS of your equations are actually equal.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for.